# How to check where my code is slow using STM32 CubeIDE?

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide

Is it possible to check where my code is slow, or to check how much time
is being taken in individual functions in STM32 CubeIDE?

Comment: If you have a debugger with full trace capability and an STM32 part with the _Embedded Trace Macrocell_ (ETM) and a debugger that supports trace timing, you can measure it directly and profile your code.  I am not sure CubeIDE supports that.  https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/can-st-cube-ide-do-execution-time-profiling/.

Comment: Otherwise you will necessarily have to instrument your code to capture timing information.  Some debuggers support using the Instrumentation Trace Macrocell (ITM) for that. Again possibly not CubeIDE. You can use the SYSCLK or toggle GPIO and monitor with a scope or logic analyser.

Comment: Code itself is never "slow" it runs at a more-or-less constant rate - the problem is _inefficiency_ - spending time executing more instructions than necessary.  Working out where your code is inefficient can generally be done by inspection (at least to select a target for more precise timing).  Lengthy operations in including moving large amounts pf data, floating point operations without an FPU, frequent dynamic memory allocation, C string operations, lengthy iterations.